# Is AWS Access Key / Secret Key encrypted during transport and Is it safe to be used on public WIFI hotspot?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was connected to a public WIFI hotspot and I executed this command:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
```

and it successfully returned all my EC2 instance information.(since I have my AWS Access Key / Secret Key configured in my local machine)

To prepare for the worst, let us assume this public wifi is not safe and hacked, now does my action above expose the AWS Access Key / Secret Key?

P.S. If on public WIFI, I only visit HTTPS websites, is there still any security risks regarding my credentials to these websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have to worry about your key being stolen in transit -- HTTPS will do a *reasonably* good job of ensuring that you're really talking to AWS, and all communication will be encrypted.

If your computer is hacked, though, then all bets are off.  The danger of this is significantly increased on a public network.

Comment: Thank you. What exactly is going on behind AWS Access/Secret key though? Is it SSH or HTTPS?

Comment: The AWS cli command and the AWS SDK use HTTPS to call the service interfaces in AWS.

Answer (score 1):

No, It will not expose anything, until you will not share your username with a hacker to ease his job of hacking your account.

Your Access key is like a username and the secret key is like a password.
*The Access/Secret key use a secure protocol to call the AWS information/API.*

You can also create and use temporary access keys, known as temporary security credentials. The advantage of temporary security credentials is that they are short term. After they expire, they're no longer valid.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please elaborate more on `The Access/Secret key use a secure protocol to call the AWS information/API.` ? I did not know that there is a thing called `AWS information/API`.  Is it a special secure protocol they made?  I'm really new to AWS, just started to use it.

Comment: By default, the AWS CLI sends requests to AWS services by using HTTPS on TCP port 443. To use the AWS CLI successfully, you must be able to make outbound connections on TCP port 443.